# VB: replace IIF function call in class instantiation

Tags: vb.net

I have the following class in VB (shortened):

```
Public Class MyClass

    Public Const DefaultParam As Single = 0.2F

    Public Sub New(ByVal param1 As Single, ByVal param2 As Single, Optional ByVal param3 As Single = 0.0F)

        MyClass.New(param1, param2, 0.0F, 0.0F, CSng(IIf(param3 <= 0.0F, DefaultParam, param3)))
        // .. here is some code
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

I need to replace 'iif' function call by some other VB or C# code (this is a requirement).
I tried to write my own function:

```
Public Function GetMyValue(ByVal myParam As Single) As Single
        If myParam <= 0.0F Then
            Return DefaultParam
        End If

        Return myParam
    End Function
```

And call it like this:

```
MyClass.New(param1, param2, 0.0F, 0.0F,CSng(GetMyValue(param3)))
```

But I get compiler error:

> Cannot access non-shared function 'GetMyValue' in shared context.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You have "Public Sub New" but are calling the constructor as "MyClass.New". I think your sample code doesn't represent what you are doing.

Comment: The compiler error comes from the function not being defined as `Shared` (`Static` in C#), and in your case you can use the normal If function: `If(param3 <= 0.0F, DefaultParam, param3)`. However, I see no overload of your `New` sub to accept that many parameters, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @SpyrosP. I just didn't put all overloads here, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work correctly. If both value are of type Single, you should use simple 'if'.

```
   MyClass.New(param1, param2, 0.0F, 0.0F, If(param3 <= 0.0F, DefaultParam, param3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your function declaration:

```
Public Shared Function GetMyValue(ByVal myParam As Single) As Single
```

This will allow you to make the function call without having to instantiate the class.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with VB, mostly working with C#.